# Storing large dataset

Tags: mysql, database, storage, data-science, data-storage

I'm trying to determine the best way to store sampled data from a multiple gigasample digitizer. I want to use an SQL database to store metadata and other information, but I don't see a way to feasibly store the bulk of the data, which is in chunks of under 500kB, generated at a rate of 10hz. How can I store this data and link it to the database in an efficient way?

Comment: This is way too open-ended a question. Store it with computers! On hard drives! Or maybe SSD! Or possibly *The Cloud*. Unless you can speak in terms of code, in terms of schema, in terms of practical, concrete terms, this is off-topic here. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: I'm not asking where to store it. Obviously this data is being stored on a computer. I need to decide the best place to store this data in a high performance, short term method before moving to HDF5 for long term storage. I have to use something beyond just an SQL database as the data volume exceeds practical row sizing without creating excessive tables. All that I have seen for similar layout schema are using links to external files as a pseudojoin. This is mostly functional, but I want to know if there's a better method. I intentionally avoided detail to keep this from being an XY problem.

Comment: There's no single answer for this. You'll need to explore and find out. Maybe MySQL works or maybe it's a huge disaster. Maybe Cassandra or Postgres or flat files or punchcards works.

Comment: I've been exploring. There's not a lot of detail on why solutions exist. The common answer to any similar question is to use a FILESTREAM (if available in your SQL flavor) or to do basically the same thing manually.  The other common answer is to not do this with no other solutions given. Most other questions revolve around the stance that databases are for structured data, not blobs. I am working with large structured data. I can make any of the solutions work, but I'm interested in making things work optimally before I spend a week going the wrong way.

Comment: That's why I recommended those other services. You can hire experts for as little as an hour to get the information you need and go off confidently. Here we can't really speculate. This is strictly question-answer and the answer is pretty much "It depends..."